# What's this pattern in the assembly code generated by go compiler?

Tags: assembly, go

I was debugging an irrelevant issue in the Linux kernel and saw the [etcd](https://github.com/coreos/etcd) process, which was managed by supervisor, was repeatedly hitting page fault exception and receiving SIGSEGV.

I got curious and used objdump to disassemble the program, and found the faulting amd64 instruction to be:

```
89 04 25 00 00 00 00    mov    %eax,0x0
```

I then looked at the disassembly of a hello world program. I saw a very common pattern in code generated by go compiler, that is at the end of a function, right after `ret`, there's a `mov` followed by a `jmp` back into the function. For example,

```
0000000000400c00 <main.main>:
  400c00:       64 48 8b 0c 25 f0 ff    mov    %fs:0xfffffffffffffff0,%rcx
  400c07:       ff ff
        ...
  400c4b:       48 83 7c 24 48 00       cmpq   $0x0,0x48(%rsp)
  400c51:       74 59                   je     400cac <main.main+0xac>
  400c53:       48 c7 04 24 c0 fc 47    movq   $0x47fcc0,(%rsp)
  400c5a:       00

        ...
  400cab:       c3                      retq
  400cac:       89 04 25 00 00 00 00    mov    %eax,0x0
  400cb3:       eb 9e                   jmp    400c53 <main.main+0x53>
```

Is this some trick played by go? If so, how does it work? I'm guessing at `0x400c51` it jumps to `0x400cac`, triggers a `SIGSEGV`, which is handled and then the next instruction jumps back to `0x400c53`.

Comment: `mov    %eax,0x0` doesn't move a register to an immediate. It moves a register to address 0 (unless there was a fixup done at some point that replaced 0 with something else). If you wanted to attempt to move `eax` to the immediate 0 (which wouldn't assemble) you would write `mov %eax, $0` (with a dollar sign).

Comment: @Michael, thanks for the correction. I got confused.

Comment: no compiler will set a register to 0 by mov in optimized mode. They'll use [`xor reg, reg`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33666617/995714)

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: This is AT&T syntax assembly. The operand order is `src, dest`.

Comment: I think asking this question on the official user list has better chance of getting response from the core Go developers: https://groups.google.com/d/forum/golang-nuts

Comment: is there some code writing an adress to 400caf before jumping to 400cac?

Comment: It could be [this](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/runtime/proc.go#L203) which is used to cause a crash if exit should somehow fail. Useful when porting Go to a new platform.

Comment: While `@thwd`'s comment is probably a spot on, please do what `@kostya` suggested and post a message to the mailing list: AFAIK, none of the Go core devs read this SO tag anyway but they do frequent the mailing list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got some answers from the Go developers: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/_7yio3ZfVBE

Basically, this pattern is the nil check in the obsolete implementation. Quoted is the answer from Keith Randall.

> If the pointer is nil, it jumps to an instruction that generates a 
>   fault.  That fault is used to start a nil ptr panic.
>
> It's a pretty inefficient code sequence.  The jmps never appear to be 
>   used.  Upgrade to a more recent Go version and you'll see it has been 
>   improved.

Comment: gcc often puts short blocks of code after the first `ret` in a function for the body of an `if` statement in C.  So when the condition is true, it jumps down there and does something, then jumps back.  This makes the not-true case more efficient, because there's no taken conditional branch and no unconditional branch.  It looks like the Go compiler used the same structure for code that was meant to crash, not return.  That's my guess as to why that pattern existed in the first place: it was natural for gcc to make code like that for `if(null pointer) panic`